# Java Jericho hyperlink parsing

Tags: java, parsing, jericho-html-parser

I'm trying to figure out a way to get all hyperlinks in a webpage - except if they are in an anchor tag().

For this I'm using the Jericho parser.

My initial approach was to take the difference between 
`List<Element> elementList = source.getAllElements();` and 
`getAllElements(HTMLElementName.A)`, but other elements might also contain an anchor link within them, so I don't think that's the right approach.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) for Html processing.

Here's an example how you can get all links (= `a`-tag with `href`-attribute):

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http:// - link here -").get(); // Connect to website and parse its html
Elements links = doc.select("a[href]"); // Select all 'a'-tags' with 'href'-attribute

for( Element element : links ) // iterate over all links (example)
{
    // process element
}
```

**Documentation:**

- [Selector API (DOM API is available too)](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html)
- [Cookbook *(Examples)*](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/)
- [list links `(Example)`](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/example-list-links)
- [JavaDoc](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/)

Btw. can you explain this a bit more?

> except if they are in an anchor tag